# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. - App.module.ts already has right references

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My App.module.ts looks like this:

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        //import HttpclientModule after BrowserModule
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        DefaultModule,
    
  ],
```

I use in another component ->  test.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let list of JsonData">

{{title}}

</div>
```

But I don't understand the error message?

the JsonData structure looks like that:

```
Downloaded blob content {
"name": "test_sensor",
"timestamp": 1597925753,
"value": 12
}
```

The json-data.service.ts, where I retrieve the data from the Blobstorage:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { JsonData } from '../models/jsondata';

import {
  BlobServiceClient,
  BlobDownloadResponseModel
} from "@azure/storage-blob";




@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

    export class JsonDataService {
      private account = environment.ACCOUNT_NAME;
      
      private sas = environment.SAS;
      private blobServiceClient
    
      constructor() { this.blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient( `https://${this.account}.blob.core.windows.net${this.sas}`)}
    
    
      getData(): Promise<JsonData[]> {
    
        /*const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
    
          `https://${this.account}.blob.core.windows.net${this.sas}`,
        );*/
    
    
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            
        
    
          const containerName = "container1";
          const containerClient = this.blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
    
    
    
    
          //list blobs
          let i = 1;
          
          async function main() {
            i = 1;
            for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
    
              console.log(`Blob ${i++}: ${blob.name}`);
              const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name);
    

    
              const downloadBlockBlobResponse =  await blockBlobClient.download(0);
              const download = await blobToString(await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody)
         
              console.log("Downloaded blob content",
               download
              );
    
            }
    
          }
    
          //BROWSER ONLY A HELPER METHOD USED TO CONVERT A BROWSER BLOB INTO STRING
          async function blobToString(blob: Blob): Promise<string> {
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             fileReader.onloadend = (ev: any ) => {
               resolve(ev.target!.result);
             };
             fileReader.onerror = reject;
             fileReader.readAsText(blob);
            });
          }
    
          main().catch((err) => {
            console.error("Error running sample:", err.message);
          })
    
        })
    
      }
    
    }
```

then in the test.component.ts file I want to display the json structure of the downloaded blob file.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { JsonDataService } from 'src/app/services/json-data.service';
import { JsonData } from 'src/app/models/jsondata';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts2',
  templateUrl: './posts2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts2.component.scss'],
  providers: [JsonDataService]
})



export class Posts2Component implements OnInit {
  @Input() title: string;
  jsondatas: Array<JsonData> = [];
  jsondata: JsonData;
  name: String;
  timestamp: string;
  value: number;


  

  constructor(private jsonService: JsonDataService) {
  
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.jsonService.getData()
      .then(results => this.jsondatas = results);

    console.log(this.jsonService) **somehow this only shows the credentials (ACCOUNT, SAS) and not get back the jsondata**

  }



}
```

Comment: How does your JsonData look like, is it actually Iteratable?

Comment: Also please add more context to the structure of your app. In wich modules do the components reside in and how do the imports look like?

Comment: @JanKrüger thanks for your response. I edited the code. I only have in one file one dataset which i stored as jsonData.

Comment: I see I only stored 1 dataset in that jsonfile, so it is not iteratable?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import CommonModule to use directive *ngFor. It is part of CommonModule. Please add the common module to the module where TestComponent is declared.

```
import { CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
  imports: [
CommonModule
],
```

Please find more info here: https://angular.io/guide/frequent-ngmodules

Comment: He already has BrowserModule imported, wich re-exports CommonModule and ApplicationModule.  
[Docs](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/BrowserModule)

Comment: I am assuming he is using ngFor in TestComponent which is not the part of current Module(code he has added). So, he need to add CommonModule to that particular Module when Test component is declared. Even the error he has mentioned says the same thing. I guess he can help us with more details.

Comment: @PrinceIsNinja how to import CommonModule in the Test component and how to use this in that component?

Comment: I can see in your code that you have a component called Posts2Component. To use a component in app we register it with a module by adding it in declarations array .. Right? In that particular module - Import CommonModule like i did and then add  it inside imports array. https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules#how-to-make-a-feature-module